# Help needed with advanced mathematical manipulation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

I have been struggling recently a lot with so called *"clever"* manipulations.

Here is an example:

\begin{align*}
&(1+a)(1+a^2)(1+a^4)(1+a^8)\cdots (1+a^{2^n})\\
&= \frac{(1-a)(1+a)(1+a^2)(1+a^4)(1+a^8) \cdots(1+a^{2^n})}{1-a}\\
&= \frac{(1^2-a^2)(1^2+a^2)(1+a^4)(1+a^8)\cdots(1+a^{2^n})}{1-a}\\
&= \frac{(1^4-a^4)(1^4+a^4)(1+a^8)\cdots(1+a^{2^n})}{1-a}\\
&= \frac{1-a^{2^{n+1}}}{1-a}
\end{align*}

I could never in a thousand year guess myself to multiply with $1-a$,  I tried to think the expression as $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)\cdots(x-d)$ but got no answer.

These clever manipulations have been messing up with me. They are stopping me from learning new math and discouraging me a **lot**.

I want to know how do you approach these clever manipulations , often in middle of the question I would see $3+2\sqrt 2$ being simplified as $(1+\sqrt 2)^2$ , It is obvious but I couldn't have though of it.

I would like an exhaustive list of questions that would gradually train these skills.

Any help is greatly appreciated , it may look like a small issue but really man it is quite frustrating for me. I know experience and practice helps but still I need to have a way to gain that.

Comment: this question is all about $(x + y)(x - y) = x^2 - y^2$
here, let $x = 1$ and $y = a^{n}$

Comment: A way is to record the tricks you see employed in a given solution and try them next time you see a new problem. You will build over time a larger and larger set of tricks from which you can trial and error to see what works.

Comment: Btw the $3+2\sqrt 2$ should be a rather standard one

Comment: I understand your struggle since I had the same! You just have to practice a lot and without even realizing you'll find yourself having those "clever" ideas. For me it helped a lot to look a discrete mathematics textbook and doing a lot of exercises! But please don't let that stop you from learning new maths!!

Comment: In a sense, this site with its couple million answers is a list of such tricks. Mind you, that list is not comprehensive :-) I'm afraid that also means that I want to vote to close the question as *Too Broad*.

Comment: @summer-sky-FREEDOM I know but that is the main crux , you need to figure out and my question is exactly how would I have thought of it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The problem is that a lot 'em seem to be at undergrad level and I am focusing more in the basic mainpulations. As for being rad , maybe yes . I tried to put the context down and narrow it. Please tell any other info needed to maye narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Then about *how to figure these out?* Practice and experiment. Here you could start out by expanding out
$$(1+a)(1+a^2)=1+a+a^2+a^3$$ 
as well as
$$(1+a)(1+a^2)(1+a^4)=1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4+a^5+a^6+a^7.$$ Then you might recall the formula for a geometric sum:
$$1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^k=\frac{1-q^{k+1}}{1-q}.$$
At that point you would be very close. Just connect the dots.

Comment: @Divide1918 Hmm.. I remember  reading something alon similar lines said by Descartes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A message you can read in that explanation is that building your repertory of tricks takes a lot of time. Many years.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are right but I didn't remember the geometric sum formula. Usually this is the way i approach problems. Get my hands dirty with simpler cases and move onto complex ones finding any patterns and then trying to explain those patterns. Maybe I got allured by the notion of elegance.

Comment: @ml64 Thanks man, any suggestions for a book. Looks like discrete maths is where I need to focus.

Comment: Very glad to hear that @MohdSaad! Experimenting is the way. We all have a lot of dirt on our hands. Comes with the territory (or learning the trade).

Comment: I learned with " Invitation to discrete mathematics" by Matousek

Comment: I forgot say that the list of tricks builds on itself. Like a pyramid. A new trick depending on a few earlier ones. That is one of the reasons you need to give yourself time to build your own repertory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the example you've used. Here you've just used the fact that [$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+\dots+x y^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Difference_of_Two_Powers), where they put $x=1$ and $y=a^2$. From there you can simply derive the final result.

You need to practise a lot, but more importantly you need to understand fundamentally what is going on and how this solution is derived. Even some mathematicians might struggle a bit with this and that is where your advantage comes in, when you learn some topic you'll most likely be learning from some book (if you don't then you should) and in books all of the problems that use a similiar solution should all be in one place, so you actually know which idea to use. All you need is to practice a lot of these problems. When you learn one technique go on to another one and then another one. After that when you encounter some problem where you need to use algebraic manipulations, you'll know a lot of different ways to solve them, but then you need to find which one is the best to use. After some trial and error, you'll get the idea of which algebraic manipulation in different scenarios.

TL;DR Just a lot of practice.

Answer (score 1):

One generic method is asking oneself: *how do I make a transformation formula appear*?

This is an approximate pattern-matching process: which transformation formula that I know appears, even partially, in the expression at hand? That must be combined with two basic rules:

1. If an additive term in a formula I try to make appear is missing, we are allowed to introduce that term (so that the transformation formula appears) and subtract it (so that the value of the original expression is kept).
2. If it's some multiplicative term that's missing, we are allowed to introduce this term and divide by it (but we must add the hypothesis that this term is not zero).

In the first example $(1+a)(1+a^2)(1+a^4)(1+a^8)\cdots(1+a^{2^n})$, we want to realize there is an opportunity to apply $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$ with $x=1$, and $y=a$ then $y=a^2$, $a^4$, and so on. Putting $1-a$ as denominator is a case of rule 2.

In the second example $3+2\sqrt 2$, we want to thing about $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$, with $2\sqrt 2$ the term $2xy$, and $3$ the other terms $x^2+y^2$. To match $2\sqrt 2$ and $2xy$, we try $x=1$ and $y=\sqrt2$, and realize that fits $x^2+y^2=3$ (we could reformulate that last step with rule 1, but here it's overkill).

In my experience, the more exercises needing that thought process are made, the more it become instinctive to think about the right transformation to apply. Not that that the right transformation always is quite the first to pop up in mind, or that this heuristic always works!

For training, it helps to works out how we solve the problem is the more obvious direction: starting from $\frac{1-a^{2^{n+1}}}{1-a}$ or $(1+\sqrt 2)^2$. Accordingly, some (easy) exercises are on the tune: show that $3+2\sqrt 2$ can be rewritten $(1+\sqrt 2)^2$. Next level is: write $3+2\sqrt 2$ as a square.

There's a lot of that in math, e.g. when it comes to integrals. A good thing is that when this thought process is acquired in one's youth, there's chance a good portion of it remains for decades if used even occasionally.

Another option is to try to remember the technique that works in a given situation, as suggested in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/10277650). This works in the short term, or for techniques that one uses often. But for some persons (including me) that knowledge will fade away quicker than a few transformation formulas, and the ability to select the right one facing a given situation.

Comment: The thing I struggle exactly with is how does one figure out the transformational formula.

Comment: @Mohd Saad. A prerequisite is learning  the usual formulas; and applying them a few times in the easy direction (starting from $(1+\sqrt 2)^2$ or $1-a^{2^n}$. Then a process to figure out the right formula could be to try them one by one. But that's not how it happens: the human brain is good at pattern matching, and the process of matching happens unconsciously, much like one does not recognize a person from a picture or a song from earing it by scanning all known persons or songs.